# Можно ли так выразиться: "Эксклюзивная девушка"?

Tags: употребление-слов

Можно выразиться относительно человека, например, "Эксклюзивная девушка...", или это будет грубейшей ошибкой? Увидела в рубрике "Знакомства". Разве можно так сказать по отношению к одушевленному предмету?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выражаться можете как угодно. Запретов у нас ведь нет даже в медиа-пространстве, кроме мата. Только не будет ли это издевательством над языком? Точнее, будет ли это русским языком?

Answer (score 1):

В ироническо-юмористическом смысле — можно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, если учесть, что "эксклюзивный" (исключительный) - непереведённое слово из английского, попавшее в российскую рекламу подобно тому, как вместо белков в ней возникли "протеины", а вместо оливкового масла "масло оливы". В английском понятие 'exclusive girls' (отменные девушки) используется в рекламе эскортных (и "смежных") услуг. Если вам нужен другой смысл, лучше обойтись русскими прилагательными.